Popup.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d.ActionsCollection is not a constructor
The popup is not opening when I click on the point in the map and it leaves an error in the console, "Popup.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d.ActionsCollection is not a constructor"
the code is provided below,
require(["esri/WebMap", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/widgets/Search", "esri/widgets/Zoom", "esri/widgets/Locate", "esri/popup/content/ImageMediaInfo", "esri/config", "esri/portal/Portal"], function (WebMap, MapView, Search, Zoom, Locate, ImageMediaInfo, esriConfig, Portal) {
    esriConfig.portalUrl = "https://test.org/portal";

    webmap = new WebMap({
        portalItem: {
            id: "*********",
        },
    });

   
    var view = new MapView({
        map: webmap,
        container: "viewDiv",
        center: [-95.9406, 41.26],
        zoom: 13,
        
        basemap: "topo",
        constraints: {
            minZoom: 12,
           
        },
    });
    // webmap.loadStatus
    view.when(function () {
        webmap
            .load()
            .then(function () {
                
                return webmap.basemap.load();
            })
            .then(function () {
                
                let allLayers = webmap.allLayers;
                

                var promises = allLayers.map(function (layer) {
                    return layer.load();
                });
                return Promise.all(promises.toArray());
            })
            .then(function (layers) {
                webmap.removeAll();

                

                
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // the webmap or portal failed to load
                console.log("The resource failed to load: ", error);
            });
    });
});


Which version are you using?

The version is 4.29 (https://js.arcgis.com/4.29/)
